# How to check an uploaded texture in OpenGL ES 2.0 in Android?

Tags: android, debugging, opengl-es, textures

I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0 in an Android application to **upload a texture atlas**, which can be quite big in size (let's say 4096x4096). (I'm uploading the corresponding bitmap data in smaller pieces, using the `texSubImage2D()` function.)

When I'm done, I'd like to **check the texture** that I've just finished uploading. I'd like to do this from the development environment - in a similar way that you can check a `Bitmap` from Android Studio while debugging, when it displays the contents of the `Bitmap` as an image.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (based on [this screenshot](https://google.github.io/gapid/images/screenshots/textures.png)) that Google's open source **[GAPID (Graphics API Debugger)](https://github.com/google/gapid)** should be able to do this. (Apparently it used to be part of Android Studio, but not any more - now it's a standalone application.) Version 1.0 was released in 2017 December.

Unfortunately, there is a yet unfixed [issue](https://github.com/google/gapid/issues/1508) that prevents me using it in my application (it exits right after startup), but it should hopefully be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any functionality in Android IDEs which will do this, as the debugger doesn't have visibility of the graphics memory.

Some graphics-specific tools will support viewing texture data - such as Mali Graphics Debugger if you are using a Mali GPU - but in all honesty it's probably easier just to bind the texture as a color attachment of a framebuffer object and then call `glReadPixels()` to read back the color data. If you want to reduce the size because 4kx4k is too large then downscale it into a second texture via an FBO before reading it back